# HTTP Live Streaming : The Linux nightmare

Tags: linux, http, streaming, mp3, debian

I'm working on a music VOD app on iPhone, and thanks to Apple guidelines, I have to run a HTTP Live Streaming in order to be accepted on the AppStore. But, since Apple doesn't care about 98% of servers on earth, they don't provide their so magical HTTP Live Streaming Tools for Linux-based systems. And from this point, the nightmare starts.

My goal is simple : Take an MP3, segmentate it and generate a simple .m3u8 index file.
I googled "HTTP Live Streaming Linux" and "Oh great ! lots of people have already done that"!

First, I visited [the (so famous) post by Carson McDonald](http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/452/iphone-http-streaming-with-ffmpeg-and-an-open-source-segmenter/).
Result : the svn segmentate.c was old, buggy and a nightmare to compile (Nobody in this world can precise what version of ffmpeg they are using !).
Then I came across [the Carson's git repo](https://github.com/carsonmcdonald/HTTP-Live-Video-Stream-Segmenter-and-Distributor/tree/v2), but too bad, there is a lot of annoying ruby stuff and live_segmenter.c can't take mp3 files.

Then I searched more deeply. I found [this stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247789/http-live-streaming-segmenting-mp3-on-linux), and it's exactly what I want to do. So I have followed the advice from juuni to use [this script (httpsegmenter)](http://code.google.com/p/httpsegmenter/). Result: Impossible to compile anything, 2 days of works and finally I managed to compile it (ffmpeg 8.1 w/ httpsegmenter rev17). And no, this is not a good script, it does take mp3 files, but the ts files generated and the index file can't be read by a player.

Then the author of the post krisbulman, came with a solution, and even gave a patched version of m3u8-segmenter by his own ([git repo](http://github.com/krisbulman/m3u8-segmenter)). I test it : doesn't compile, do nothing. So I took the original version from johnf https://github.com/johnf/m3u8-segmenter. I managed to compile and miracle it works (not really). 
I used this command line (ffmpeg 0.8.1):

```
ffmpeg -er 4 -i music.mp3 -f mpegts -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -ab 128k -vn - | m3u8-segmenter -i - -d 10 -p outputdir/prefix -m outputdir/output.m3u8 -u http://test.com/
```

This script encode my mp3 file (it takes 4 seconds, too long), and pass it to the m3u8-segmenter to segment it into 10 seconds .TS files.

I tested this stream with Apple's mediastreamvalidator on my mac, and it said that it was OK. So i played it into quicktime, but there is about 0.2 seconds blank between each .TS files !!

So here is my situation, it's a nightmare, I can't get a simple mp3 stream over the HLS protocol. Is there a simple WORKING solution to segmentate a mp3 ? Why can't I directly segmentate the mp3 file into multiple mp3 files like Apple's mediafilesegmenter does?

Comment: Your English is fine, but your post is long and incoherent.  Could you condense it, and get it to focus on the key question?

Comment: The main question is : Is there a simple working solution to segmentate an mp3 file on Debian ?

Comment: Well, that explains that outrrrrageous acccceent.

Comment: abandon hope all ye who enter

Comment: For those of us looking in to open source HTTP live streaming options - This post actually provides a lot of useful links all in one place.

Comment: Did you find a good solution?

Answer (score 5):

Use libfaac insteam of libmp3lame which eliminates the 0.2 second break.

Answer (score 4):

Elastic Transcoder Service - if you don't need AES encryption just throw your MP3 in an S3 bucket and be done with it:

http://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/

You can then even add Cloudfront CDN support. (P.S. I fully appreciate your pain, this whole space is a nightmare).

Answer (score 2):

For live streaming only, you should try Nginx with RTMP module for this one. https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module 
Live HLS works pretty good but with looooong buffer.
However, it does not support on-demand HLS streaming.

Piece of module`s config for example

```
# HLS requires libavformat & should be configured as a separate
# NGINX module in addition to nginx-rtmp-module:
# ./configure ... --add-module=/path/to/nginx-rtmp-module/hls ...
# For HLS to work please create a directory in tmpfs (/tmp/app here)
# for the fragments. The directory contents is served via HTTP (see
# http{} section in config)
#
# Incoming stream must be in H264/AAC/MP3. For iPhones use baseline H264
# profile (see ffmpeg example).
# This example creates RTMP stream from movie ready for HLS:
#
# ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -re -i movie.avi  -vcodec libx264 
#    -vprofile baseline -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -ac 1 
#    -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/hls/movie
#
# If you need to transcode live stream use 'exec' feature.
#
application hls {
    live on;
    hls on;
    hls_path /tmp/app;
    hls_fragment 5s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What problems were you having with httpsegmenter?  It's a single C source file that only links against some libraries provided by ffmpeg (or libav).  I maintain a Gentoo ebuild for it, as I use it to time-shift talk radio.  If you're running Gentoo, building is as simple as this:

```
sudo bash -l
layman -S
layman -a salfter
echo media-video/httpsegmenter ~\* >>/etc/portage/package.accept_keywords
emerge httpsegmenter
exit
```

On Ubuntu, I had to make sure libavutil-dev and libavformat-dev were both installed, so the build looks something like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libavutil-dev libavformat-dev
git clone https://gitlab.com/salfter/httpsegmenter.git
cd httpsegmenter
make -f Makefile.txt
sudo make -f Makefile.txt install
```

Once it's built (and once I have an audio source URL), usage is fairly simple: curl to stream the audio, ffmpeg to transcode it from whatever it is at the source (often MP3) to AAC, and segmenter to chunk it up:

```
curl -m 3600 http://invalid.tld/stream | \
ffmpeg -i - -acodec libvo_aacenc -ac 1 -ab 32k -f mpegts - 2>/dev/null | \
segmenter -i - -d 20 -o ExampleStream -x ExampleStream.m3u8 2>/dev/null
```

This grabs one hour of streaming audio (needs to be MP3 or AAC, not Flash), transcodes it to 32 kbps mono AAC, and chunks it up for HTTP live streaming.  Have it dump into a directory served up by your webserver and you're good to go.

Once the show's done, converting to a single .m4a that can be served up as a podcast is also simple:

```
cat `ls -rt ExampleStream-*.ts` | \
ffmpeg -i - -acodec copy -absf aac_adtstoasc ExampleStream.m4a 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I am using this in VLC:

```
## To start playing the playlist out to the encoder
cvlc -vvv playlist.m3u --sout rtp:127.0.0.1 --ttl 2

## To start the encoder
cvlc rtp://  --sout='#transcode{acodec=mp3,ab=96}:duplicate{dst=std{access=livehttp{seglen=10,splitanywhere=true,delsegs=true,numsegs=15,index=/var/www/vlctest/mystream.m3u8,index-url=http://IPANDPORT/vlctest/mystream-########.ts},mux=ts,dst=/var/www/vlctest/mystream-########.ts},select=audio}'
```

I had problems if I didn't stream the playlist file to another copy of VLC, the first step is optional if you already have a live streaming source. (but you can use any source for the "encoder" portion).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use our media services on Windows Azure platform: http://mingfeiy.com/how-to-generate-http-live-streaming-hls-content-using-windows-azure-media-services/

You could encode and stream your video in HLS format by using our portal with no configuration and coding required.

Answer (score -1):

Your English is fine.

Your frustration is apparent.

Q: What's the real issue here? It sounds like you just need a working HLS server, correct?  Because of Apple requirements, correct?

Can you use any of the ready-made implementations listed here:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming

Comment: The real question is : Is there a simple working solution to segmentate an mp3 file on Debian ?

I need to stream a LOT of minutes, and ready-made often are paying solutions. Do you know one which is entirely free even with a lots of stream ?

Comment: Q: Why Debian OS?  What's wrong with a Magnetix server, for example?  Or any of the other suggested alternatives?  Are you willing to pay for a commercial solution?

Comment: I'm not going to pay a commercial solution for such a simple stuff. I use Debian OS because I need apache, php, mysql and a bunch of other tools...

I don't understand why i would have to install a Magnetix server for a so simple (in theory) thing to do...

Comment: I'm going to test VLC server, if it works i will make a post about it

Comment: @Ethan0026: Cool - please do.  I was afraid you were complaining about Linux just because you were too cheap to buy the appropriate commercial solution.  I'm extremely glad that's not the case.  You clearly like and respect Linux (yay!), you just haven't been able to find an appropriate HLS solution(nobody ever said *anything* from Apple was going to be Open-Source friendly!).  Good luck with VLC - please keep us posted!  Your .. PSM

Comment: finally vlc server is not a good solution... there is absolutely no updated version of vlc for debian squeeze (version 1.2 or newer)...

I keep believing that maybe http://code.google.com/p/httpsegmenter/ is the right solution, but i have no idea which is the right version of ffmpeg to use w/

...

Comment: Suggestion: send an e-mail to the httpsegmenter owner (his name is on the "People" tab on the project page).